# What are the difference between the Bloqs addon and the EE Fluid fields?

Tags: fluid-field

I have a question about the difference between the native EE Fluid fields and the Bloqs addon.

Both manage a collection of fields, but what are the advantages of Bloqs versus the native EE Fluid fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used either of these but I think they do the same things. I guess the advantages of fluid field is "no-brainer" when it's time to update!  Less add-on you have easier the updates are...

Comment: Thanks , you are right, now it'more clear.Yes, less addon is better.